# Format decimal to money c# aspx from sql

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Hi I have this code in my .cs file and the output is 100449.00 but I want it to format into money like 100,449.00. This is my code to show the value in the label.

```
billing.Text = "$" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Billing"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
billing.Text = "$" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Billing"].ToString("N");
```

Per [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd(v=vs.110).aspx).

Edit: what's returned is an `object` which you need to cast to a decimal. Try:

```
((decimal)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Billing"]).ToString("N");
```

Comment: I get this error: No overload for method 'ToString' takes '1' arguments

Comment: @ParbhuBissessar are you sure that your value is in `decimal` ? does not seem to be...

Comment: I'm sure that it is.

Comment: @ParbhuBissessar that makes one wonder, because the documentation states clearly that this overload exist.

Comment: What's returned by the `[]` operator is an object, therefore a cast to a decimal is needed. Please see my last edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
billing.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Billing"].ToString("c");
```

Comment: OP asked to print out something like 100,449.00, this prints $100,449.00.

Comment: I get this error: No overload for method 'ToString' takes '1' arguments

Comment: @ytoledano i gave the op what they wanted, not what they asked for.

Comment: @ytoledano The OP had the dollar sign hard coded at the beginning of the line. However, you cannot go from an object `["billing"].ToString()` with a format specifier as it is a nullable of unknown format type

Answer (score 0):

Coming from a `DataTable` requires us to convert to a non-nullable type before we format as text.

We actually have a few different ways to do the formatting. Your post has a hardcoded dollar sign preceding the value, in which case we can use either the **F2** or **N2** format strings to give us a decimal point with 2 places to the right and append that to the dollar sign you have in there:

```
billing.Text = "$" +  ((decimal)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Billing"]).ToString("F2");
// 123456.7890 will display as $123456.78

billing.Text = "$" +  ((decimal)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Billing"]).ToString("N2");
// 123456.7890 will display as $123,456.78
```

Another option is to use the **C** format which will add in the cultural specific currency symbol and numeric format (decimal points, commas) for us

```
billing.Text = ((decimal)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Billing"]).ToString("C");
// 123456.7890 will display as
//    $123,456.78   en-US
//    123 456.78€   fr-FR
// you could also add a second overload to the ToString to specify
```